# How to hide number pad, I'm use Xamarin iOS (C#)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm found answer for my question on objective-C, but I'm don't search it in Xamarin iOS.
So I have field where user write phone number, when this field editing appear keyboard, number pad type. But this keyboard don't hide and don't have hide button.

in android application for this problem I use code:

```
one.Click += delegate
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(ulitsa.WindowToken, 0);
        };
```

In my iOS app this code don't work.
My code in iOS:

```
            tel.ShouldReturn = delegate {
            tel.ResignFirstResponder ();

            //tel.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;

            return true;
        };
```

This code work for default keyboard type. In keyboard type number pad I have result in screenshot:

[image]

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: It's no standard way to do this. Common decision - Done button on the navigation panel, or you can add custom button over the keyboard.

Comment: How I can add button over the keyboard? maybe you have example?

Comment: on objective-c https://medium.com/@chan0123/missing-done-button-in-ios-d74810a409b1#.2kgnpq4w8

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Base class with helpers methods that can be used in other ViewControllers.

i.e.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Base class for Controllers that inherit from UIViewController
/// </summary>
public class SimpleViewControllerBase : UIViewController
{
    public SimpleViewControllerBase(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    /* This will add "Done" button to numeric keyboard */
    protected void AddDoneButtonToNumericKeyboard(UITextField textField)
    {

        UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f));
        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
        {
            textField.ResignFirstResponder();
        });

        toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] {
            new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
            doneButton
        };

        textField.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }
}
```

Then in your actual ViewControllers, you can do something like this:

```
public partial class ViewController : SimpleViewControllerBase
{
    public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        AddDoneButtonToNumericKeyboard("NumericTextFieldName");
    }
}
```

And of course, you have to define the name of your numeric text field in storyboard.

**The key is to have a function like AddDoneButtonToNumericKeyboard()**

End result would look like this:
[image]

Comment: This solution works like charm, even when you have multiple numeric fields. Thank you dude

Answer (score 1):

You can see this [blog](http://kockerbeck.blogspot.com/2013/11/done-button-on-ios-numberpad-with.html). It might help you a lot.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
base.ViewDidLoad ();

// Your stuff

NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver   ("UIKeyboardWillShowNotification", KeyboardWillShow);
}

 public void KeyboardWillShow(NSNotification notification)
 {
 var doneButton = new UIButton (UIButtonType.Custom);
 doneButton.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 163, 106, 53);
 doneButton.SetTitle ("DONE", UIControlState.Normal);
 doneButton.SetTitleColor (UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
 doneButton.SetTitleColor (UIColor.White, UIControlState.Highlighted);

 doneButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
 {
 // Make the Done button do its thing!  The textfield shouldn't be the   first responder
 _txtNumbers.ResignFirstResponder();
 };

 // This is the 'magic' that could change with future version of iOS
 var keyboard = _txtNumbers.WeakInputDelegate as UIView;
 if (keyboard != null)
 {
     keyboard.AddSubview (doneButton);
 }
}
```

or you can also this code

```
 this.View.EndEditing(true);
```

Comment: What type have this variable "_txtNumbers" ?

Comment: var _txtNumbers = new UITextField (new RectangleF (5, 50, 200, 20));
   _txtNumbers.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
   _txtNumbers.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect;
   View.AddSubview (_txtNumbers);

Comment: you can found the whole project here. 
https://github.com/xeb/xamarin-done-button-example

Comment: In this string "NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver ("UIKeyboardWillShowNotification", KeyboardWillShow);"
I have 2 exception

1) "Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `Foundation.NSNotificationCenter.AddObserver(Foundation.NSString, System.Action<Foundation.NSNotification>)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502)"

2)"Error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `string' expression to type `Foundation.NSString' (CS1503)"

Comment: Did you download the app from github and test ?

Comment: Yes I have Error: "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys. (doneButton.iPhone)"

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach, using a toolbar

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/ios/add-done-to-keyboard/